# Zebra RFID getBeeperVolume throws RFID_API_SUCCESS

Tags: android, rfid

I'm implementing an RFID for Android via Zebra RFID SDK. According to [the documentation](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/sdk-for-android-dg-en.pdf), you can set the volume of a beeper by `Config.setBeeperVolume` but it says so only for RFD8500. My device is a Zebra's MC3300R one and when im trying to set the beeper volume it throws an `RFID_API_SUCCESS` exception. According to documentation, the exception message is `Function succeeded`. What am I doing wrong here and why the Zebra's documentation for this SDK is so untuitive? Thanks for any help, below my little snippet of code of trying to set the beeper volume

`_reader.value!!.Config.beeperVolume = BEEPER_VOLUME.HIGH_BEEP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a further investigation and looking into source code of [Zebra RFID Demo Application](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/demo/123rfid-mobile.html) I found out that the beep sounds are not really coming from the SDK. In this demo application it is implemented via [ToneGenerator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator).
It's a little frustrating that it's not really said anywhere in the documentation that this is in fact an whole another implementation but what can I say, maybe thats my fault at all for not realizing this simple thing :)